# Prevent redirect WooCommerce checkout form after complete

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, checkout

Just trying to stop checkout form stay still after checkout form submit complete. As we know WooCommerce checkout form submission done by ajax `?wc-ajax=checkout`. As default after successfully complete an order checkout form redirect to thankyou page but that not what I want to do.

I want after successfully complete an order checkout form stay still. I will redirect later after done some my own ajax or coding.

I look WooCommerce `checkout.js` didn't find any hook or anything to do that, So here I am to ask you guys to know anyone how to do this?

NOTE: My main reason to do this, after order status and payment status before checkout gone to thankyou page but for that I need order id and that's why it need to complete first. hope it make sense.

Comment: I did something similar by overriding checkout.js

Comment: Can't do that, I'm building a free plugin so can't do that. Need proper way.

Comment: You can do it. Just dequeue it and enqueue again inside your plugin. You must have to update when WooCommerce updates the checkout.js

Answer (score 1):

The [woocommerce_payment_complete](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L2353) hook is fired when the payment is completed. The only variable passed is the order id, though from that you can get the order object, and ultimately the user.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );
function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'pending' );
    $user = $order->get_user();
    if( $user ){
        // do something with the user
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I wanted. Actually I got payment response by gateway js. and unfortunately js won't be work in this hook. So need to stop checkout being redirect after completed.

Comment: As for your information WooCommerce 4.0.0-beta.1 has that hook but not currently or older version of woocommerce have that.https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/c3d5b36474d6d1ea3e4bd396bbd5dfd8e6a2414d/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js#L517-L522